# How to make a C# or VisualBasic Strobe light (Microphone)

Tags: c#, vb.net, microphone

How to make C # or Visual Basic strobe light that flashes according to the microphone?

Comment: Wrote some code, put in an application, publish it. Anything else you need explained?

Answer (score 0):

Add a picture box to your form and then write this in the code behind :) (Without the microphone function)

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.djinmelbourne.com/lighting_effect.gif");

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
```

*Psst..
Please read the rules/FAQ's before you ask a question next time!*